# A cerca de, Há cerca de... Ortografia

Tags: ortografia

Na prova de concurso público para Professor da banca FGV, propuseram esta questão:

```
As questões notacionais da Língua Portuguesa se referem, entre 
outras coisas, a palavras e expressões que frequentemente 
provocam dúvidas em relação à sua ortografia.
A esse respeito, assinale a opção ortograficamente correta.


(A) A cerca de vinte carros enguiçados na avenida.
(B) Os livros foram vendidos há cerca de dez semanas.
(C) Os clientes esperaram o médico a cerca de duas horas.
(D) O padre falou por horas há cerca do pecado original.
(E) Os policiais estavam acerca de cem metros do assaltante.
```

Eu, prontamente, marquei a alternativa "B", sem sombra de dúvidas. Porém, ao conferir o gabarito, vi que a resposta correta é: "C". Entendo que, dependendo da interpretação, a letra C também poderia estar correta. Mas, isso não anula a opção B, que também está correta. Analisei todos os pontos, incluindo o uso de números cardinais extensos, e conclui que não há nenhum erro ortográfico ou de qualquer outro cunho que possa anular a alternativa.

Comment: ? Que interpretação faz com que C seja correta? Espera-se alguém X tempo, não _a X tempo_: "esperei-o/esperei por ele cerca de duas horas". Alternativamente, se estivermos falar de quando a espera ocorreu e não da duração, seria "há cerca de duas horas"

Comment: @Artefacto portanto, a banca errou essa questão e deveria ser anulada?

Comment: Eu acho que o C) está errado porque "esperaram (o médico) a cerca de" tem o verbo no pretérito perfeito e portanto o ["a" em "a cerca de"](https://dicionario.priberam.org/a) não faz sentido nem como artigo definido nem como preposição. Faria sentido a preposição "durante (cerca de)" ou sem preposição, só "esperaram o médico cerca de" mas que o "a" está a mais, pelo menos em português europeu não se usa e não vejo como possa fazer sentido sintaticamente.

Comment: Procurei pouco, mas parece que a expressão para "próximo de" não é "a cerca de", mas sim "cerca de".  Acho que de duas uma: ou consideram *a* parte da expressão e o detalhamento do tempo não leva preposição, como em "três anos matei um homem", ou erraram escrevendo *a*, sendo certo *há*. O que faz esse *a*?

Comment: Eis o [site](https://conhecimento.fgv.br/concursos/sme-sp/01) que contém tanto as provas quanto seus gabaritos. Está falando da prova objetiva de artes de 2023, parece. Ela tem quatro tipos diferindo na numeração das questões. E o [gabarito](https://conhecimento.fgv.br/sites/default/files/concursos/smesp-gabarito-definitivo-retificado-edital-01-efii-e-em.pdf) realmente diz que a resposta é "**C**". O estranho é que a FGV é de enorme prestígio aqui, no Brasil.

Comment: Alguém tirou o meu comentário:  "assinale a opção ortograficamente correta". Isso sugere que só tem uma, correto? Ou não? Não entendo o que fez o moderador com o meu comentário. Ainda não há nenhuma reação.

Comment: @Lambie, isso é estranho. Sim, há apenas uma correta. E segundo o gabarito oficial, a certa é a **C**.

Comment: @Schilive Eu tambem vi: cerca de, como você. Pra mim, o certo é o B).

Comment: Obrigado. Em síntese, a banca errou mas não anulou a questão para o infortúnio dos candidatos que prestaram esse concurso :/

Answer (score 1):

O gabarito certamente está errado. Isso acontece. A resposta certa é apenas a B. Não há nenhuma interpretação possível para que a C esteja certa também.

Aqui estão as frases corrigidas:

(A) **Há** cerca de vinte carros enguiçados na avenida.

(B) Os livros foram vendidos há cerca de dez semanas.

(C) Os clientes esperaram o médico **cerca de** duas horas.

(D) O padre falou por horas **acerca do** pecado original.

(E) Os policiais estavam **a cerca** de cem metros do assaltante.